# How Does Case 5 executed in this Switch statement?

Tags: c

I have a following code(which is taken from a C book):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )
{
  int k=4,j=0;

  switch(k)
  {
  case 3:
    j=300;

  case 4:
    j=400;

  case 5:
    j=500;
  }

  printf("%d",j);
}
```

When i run the above code, I get output as `500`, but I expected it to be `400`, can anyone why it is been printed `500` rather than `400`?

(I am novice in C and I couldn't figure out what is the error in it!)

Comment: Please indent your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `break;` at the end of a case block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k = 4, j = 0;
    switch(k)
    {
        case 3:
            j = 300;
            break;
        case 4:
            j = 400;
            break;
        case 5:
            j=500;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to break out of your cases otherwise it will run trough other cases:

```
int main( )
{
    int k=4,j=0;
    switch(k)
    {
    case 3:
        j=300;
        break;
    case 4:
        j=400;
        break;
    case 5:
        j=500;
        break;
    }
    printf("%d",j);
}
```

So in your case it did execute `j=400` and then went to `case 5`: and execute `j=500`

Answer (score 3):

There's no break statement after case 4, so execution "falls through" to case 5.